# Generate Ear file which includes WAR file using maven pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have EAR with an application and I need to extend this app with my own code that is packaged as a WAR. Is there a maven plugin that can help me with putting the WAR inside the EAR?

Need Automate solution for generate ear file which includes a war file

4.0.0
com.spring.example
example
1
ear
example

```
<!-- Add Spring Web and MVC dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
    
    <groupId>com.spring.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
   <type>war</type>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        
        <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-example</finalName>

    <modules>
        <webModule>
           <groupId>com.spring.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
            <uri>example.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>sexample.war</bundleFileName>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
```

maven-war-plugin
                3.0.0
                
                    WebContent
                
            
        
        ${project.artifactId} 
    

and getting error at line where dependency to generate war file . so where am missing please help me.

Comment: Is this module defined with packaging `ear` ? Apart from that is there a reason why you are using a 10 year old version of maven-ear-plugin?

Comment: Getting same error if I replcaed with <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>

Comment: Error showing  "Missing artifact com.spring.example:example:war:1''

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying, but you probably need one module/project to build the war, and then one project/module in which you pack the war in to the ear.